# How to fetch data in Laravel Eloquent way

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables.

- publishers (publisher_id, name)
- items (id, item_name, publisher_id)

Now, all I need is a "Publisher Name" and "Count for all items under each publisher".

I can do this with a simple join using a traditional way. But I am new to Laravel stuff and want to achieve this using eloquent.

Please help, 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Laravel` way. Since you didn't mention specifics, i made an example with looping your data.

```
// Get all publishers
$publishers = Publisher::all();

foreach ($publishers as $publisher)
{
    // Get name
    $publisher->name;

    // Get count with loading all items and counting em
    $publisher->items->count();

    // Get count with sql operation
    $publisher->items()->count();
}
```

The trick with count is when you access relations like so in Laravel, `$publisher->items` it will load the items into objects. If you do it like so `$publisher->items()` you will gain a `QueryBuilder` and from there you can count the items with SQL operation.

Meanwhile if you do not have the relation set up, you can do the relation in the model like so and find details on relations [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

```
public class Publisher
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Extra answer. You can query relationships, by doing a `whereHas` with the relation and a callback. So something similar to this should work in pseudo'ish code.

```
$publisherWithNewItems = Publisher::whereHas('items', function ($query) {
    $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay());
})->get();
```

Comment: Thank you "mrhn" for the quick response and solving my problem. I still need to find a way to fetch all the records (for each Publisher) in items table posted in the past 24 hours. I will dig more, Thank you very much once again!

Comment: I make an edit for that problem, if it helped you with the original answer, please accept the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Just improving @mrhm solution:

Create a `items` relationship within the `Publisher` model:

```php
public class Publisher
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

Create a `publisher` relation within the `Item` model:

```php
public class Item
{
    public function publisher()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Publisher::class);
    }
}
```

The relation below returns the Publisher who had published a specific post.

Now, to fetch the publisher name, count all publisher posts and fetch all posts published by an specific publisher in past 24 hours, you can do something like this:

```php
// Within some controller:
public function getData($publisherId)
{
    $publisher = Publisher::find($publisherId);
    $name = $publisher->name;
    $publisherPosts = $publisher->items;
    $countAllPosts = $publisher->items->count();
    $postsPast24Hours = $publisher->posts()->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay());
}
```

If you want all posts by all publishers, use this:

```php
// Within some controller:
public function getData()
{
    $data = [];
    $publishers = Publisher::all();
    foreach($publishers as $publisher) {
        $data[] = [
            'name'             => $publisher->name,
            'posts'            => $publisher->items,
            'postsPast24Hours' => $publisher->posts()->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay()),
            'countPosts'       => $publisher->items->count(),
        ];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

> Don't forget to import Carbon, Item and Publisher.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Meteus. You are awesome.

Comment: Glad that i can help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create one to one relation in you eloquent model

In your Items model

```
 public function publisher(){
   return $this->hasOne('App/Publisher'); //assuming publisher model in app directory 
}
```

then you can get it in your controller using:

```
$items = Item::with(['publisher'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use the Query builder:

```
$result = DB::table('publisher as p')
            ->select(DB::raw("p.name as publisher_name, count(*) as count"))
            ->join('items as i', 'p.publisher_id', '=', 'i.publisher_id')
            ->groupBy('publisher_name')
            ->get();
```

Sometimes I prefer to use it.

Cheers!